# Understanding the difference between the following async-await calls

Tags: c#, async-await, threadpool

Would these calls behave similarly? As in would they behave the same way async-await runs - can or cannot run on the same original thread context? Or would the first one ensure that the execution happens in a different thread context?

First way -

```
Task task = SomeAsyncTask();
await task();
```

Second way -

```
await SomeAsyncTask();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there is code between `Task task = SomeAsyncTask();` and `await task();`, your task will start executing async code and your current thread will execute that code at the same time.

Otherwise, they are equal..

```
Task task = SomeAsyncTask();
//Codes executed on current thread while SomeAsyncTask is running
await task();
```

Answer (score 1):

[All asynchronous methods start synchronously](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

That is:

```
await SomeAsyncTask();
```

is exactly the same as:

```
var task = SomeAsyncTask();
await task;
```

In both cases, `SomeAsyncTask` will run until it is either complete or hits an asynchronous `await`, at which point it returns a task. That task is then `await`ed by the calling method.